# Numerical Analysis Maximization Question

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods

ON a practice exam http://math.berkeley.edu/~mgu/MA128B2012S/SampleMidTerm.pdf

I am unsure how we can begin #2. How does the term normal equation fit in that context for the link above? I know we are effectively doing Least Squares

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is this: 
$$
\min_{P \in \mathcal{S}} \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} (f(x) - P(x))^2 dx
$$
where $\mathcal{S}$ is the set of polynomials of degree $n$. You can define an inner product
$$
\langle f,g \rangle = \int_0^1 f(x) g(x) \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} dx
$$
on functions on $[0,1]$ (suitably behaved around $0$), with corresponding norm $\|f\| = \sqrt{\langle f,f \rangle}$. Now,your problem is to minimize $\|f - P\|^2$ over $P \in \mathcal{S}$.

Since, $\mathcal{S}$ is a linear space, spanned by the function $\{g_0, g_1, g_2,\dots,g_n\}$ where $g_i(x) = x^i$, the optimal solution to your problem is characterized by the error being orthogonal to each one of these functions, that is
$$
\langle f - P, g_i\rangle = 0, \quad i = 0,1,\dots,n
$$
or 
$$
\int_0^1 [f(x) - \sum_{j=0}^n \alpha_j x^j] x^i \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}} = 0, \quad i=0,1,\dots,n.
$$
These are the normal equations which give you the coefficients $\{\alpha_j\} $ of the optimal polynomial.